# Login error with Titanium Studio

Tags: macos, titanium-mobile

I downloaded Titanium Studio from the Appcelerator website, the install went fine but I cannot login when opening the application. It tells me that "The login server returned an error. Please consult the troubleshooting page". When I do that and I try login with this command from Terminal:
`curl -v -d "un=XXXX&pw=YYYY" https://api.appcelerator.net/p/v1/sso-login` it works fine.

The next step was to run the application through the command line and see the exceptions thrown when I tried to login. This is the output in Terminal:

```
!SESSION 2014-05-05 10:24:21.165 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_37
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/nickcorin/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -keyring /Users/nickcorin/.eclipse_keyring -consoleLog -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2014-05-05 10:24:24.463
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1764)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1725)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1708)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1237)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1214)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1014)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.signIn(TitaniumUserManager.java:160)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.handlers.TitaniumSplashHandler$17.run(TitaniumSplashHandler.java:1004)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:57)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:161)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:204)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1185)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:958)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1203)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1230)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:183)
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:103)
    at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:87)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:55)
    ... 18 more
^CException in thread "Thread-1" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.closeWidget(Shell.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowWillClose(Shell.java:2327)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5530)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.JNIBridge._takedown_splash(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.JNIBridge.takeDownSplash(JNIBridge.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.takeDownSplash(Main.java:2142)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main$SplashHandler.run(Main.java:113)
```

According to the troubleshooter it could be an error with my certificate or something? But when I run the command that they ask me to, I Just get permission denied.`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect api.appcelerator.net:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >mycertfile.pem` Regardless if I sudo the commend. FYI I am running on a MacBook Pro 2013 with OSX Mavericks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error with OS X 10.10.
I downloaded the new Java versionm, then it works well: [Download](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Answer (score 1):

Are you behind a firewall or proxy, if so, studio will need to be configured for these. else try this : [Link1](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Errors+Logging+In) [Link2](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Errors_Logging_In)

Comment: Well, when I try login an OSX Window comes up asking me if it should allow incoming and outgoing connections to the application and I always say yes? Also, those two links you posted are the two that I used to get to this point now. The second step gives the command line output above.

Answer (score 1):

i got the same error with OS X 10.10 i downloaded the new java then its worked good 
[Download](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)